# Why does my jQuery slider go mad when I click a nav dot on my image slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to make a image slider with navigation dots, however when I click the dots they go mad, and don't obey the 4 second timer I have enabled.

When the page loads it works fine, and slides over the images perfectly. It is only when I click a nav dot, it moves to the next one super fast.

What am I doing wrong? On reflection, I may need to kill the timer when a nav dot is clicked, but how do I do that?

```js
        $(".left-arrow").hide();


        var numImgs = $('div.carousel-image-holder img').length;
        var addId = numImgs;

        if (numImgs == 2) {
          var clicked = 0;
          imgCount = numImgs - 2;
        } else if (numImgs <= 1) {
          $(".right-arrow").hide();
        } else {
          var clicked = 1;
          imgCount = numImgs - 1;
        }

         if (numImgs > 2) {
          for (var i = 0; i < numImgs; i++) {
            $("ul").prepend('<li class="carousel-buttons" id="carousel' + addId + '"></li>');
            var addId = addId - 1;
          }
        } else {

        }

        function goToSlide(slideNo) {

          $(".carousel-buttons").removeClass("active");
          $("#carousel" + slideNo).addClass("active");

          clicked = parseInt(slideNo);
          var adjustNumberforSlide = slideNo - 1;

          $(".carousel-image-holder").animate({
            "left": -(600 * adjustNumberforSlide) + "px"
          });

          console.log(clicked);

          if (slideNo == 1) {
            $(".left-arrow").hide();
            $(".right-arrow").show();
          } else if (slideNo == numImgs) {
            $(".right-arrow").hide();
            $(".left-arrow").show();
          } else {
            $(".right-arrow").show();
            $(".left-arrow").show();
          }

          // Set timeout to go to next slide (4 seconds)
          setTimeout(function() {
            goToSlide((clicked < numImgs ? clicked + 1 : 1));
          }, 4000);

        }

        $(".carousel-buttons").click(function() {

          var findIdClicked = $(this).attr("id");
          var splitString = findIdClicked.split("carousel")
          var findTheNumb = splitString[1];

          goToSlide(findTheNumb);

        });

        $(".carousel-buttons-container").find("li").first().addClass("active");

        $(".right-arrow").click(function() {

          if (clicked < imgCount) {

            $(".carousel-image-holder").animate({
              "left": "-=600px"
            });

            console.log(clicked);

          } else {

            $(".carousel-image-holder").animate({
              "left": "-=600px"
            });
            $(".right-arrow").hide();

            console.log(clicked);
          }

          clicked = clicked + 1;
          $(".left-arrow").show();
          $(".carousel-buttons").removeClass("active");
          $("#carousel" + clicked).addClass("active");

        });

        $(".left-arrow").click(function() {

          if (clicked > 2) {

            $(".carousel-image-holder").animate({
              "left": "+=600px"
            });

            console.log(clicked);

          } else {

            $(".carousel-image-holder").animate({
              "left": "+=600px"
            });
            $(".left-arrow").hide();

            console.log(clicked);

          }

          $(".right-arrow").show();
          clicked = clicked - 1;
          $(".carousel-buttons").removeClass("active");
          $("#carousel" + clicked).addClass("active");

        });

         // Start timer
        goToSlide(clicked);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-container">
  <div class="left-arrow"></div>
  <div class="right-arrow"></div>
  <div class="carousel-image-holder">
    <img src="education/make-a-booking.jpg" />
    <img src="education/make-a-booking.jpg" />
    <img src="ducation/make-a-booking.jpg" />
    <img src="education/make-a-booking.jpg" />
    <img src="education/make-a-booking.jpg" />
    <img src="education/make-a-booking.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="carousel-buttons-container">
  <ul>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML too.

Comment: You are stacking timeouts, you need to clear it before adding the next one - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Comment: @Blazemonger posted HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click a button, you need to clear the old loop before starting your new one. Use `clearTimeout` for this, and store the id in a global variable.

```
  // Set timeout to go to next slide (4 seconds)
  window.currentLoop = setTimeout(function() { // save the timer
    goToSlide((clicked < numImgs ? clicked + 1 : 1));
  }, 4000);
}

$(".carousel-buttons").click(function() {

  var findIdClicked = $(this).attr("id");
  var splitString = findIdClicked.split("carousel")
  var findTheNumb = splitString[1];

  clearTimeout(window.currentLoop); // clear the old timer
  goToSlide(findTheNumb);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cqn67z1n/

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thanks.